# How to translate the author line "Submitted by ... on ..."

Tags: i18n-l10n

I've created a custom content type in Drupal 8.9.1. Each content post automatically renders the line

```
Submitted by author_name on 08.07.2020 - 18:21
```

Even though my Drupal system language is set to German, I cannot find a way to show a translated version of this "submitted by" text.

When I check the translations page under `/admin/config/regional/content-language` I also see a correct translation for the segment ("Geschrieben von"). But there's no indicator how this is mapped to the actual English value.

[image]

I've also seen posts saying that you have to do that manually in the Node Template. But I have not found such template and guess the approach has changed after Drupal 7.

Comment: Please note that the search on the translations page is case-sensitive --> `S`ubmitted by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the page `/admin/config/regional/content-language` holds the actual translated text, it's not the place where the "Submitted by" translation is derived from. To do so you need to

1. Navigate to **Configuration** > **Regional & language** > **User interface translation**
2. Search for "**Submitted**" in the `String contains` field. Note the uppercase S (thank you @Hudri).
3. Now enter the translation and save it. Also note the placeholders for author and date information.

[image]